# Converting pseudo code to a recurrence relation equation?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

The following is pseudo code and I need to turn it into a a recurrence relation that would possibly have either an arithmetic, geometric or harmonic series.

Pseudo code is below.

[image]

I have so far T(n) = T(n-5) + c

Comment: what is your exact question? what are you looking for? Is it the run time complexity from recurrence relation?

Comment: Yes, I can solve that part hopefully I just need to extract the equation from that pseudo code.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: So far I have $$T(n) = T(n-5) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} c$$

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources! Please edit your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755

Answer (score 1):

> T(n) = T(n-5) + c

**Solution by substitution:**

$T(n) = T(n-5) + c..................................(1)$

therefore,  $T(n-5) = T(n-10) + c ....................(2)$

Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$, gives

$T(n) = T(n-10) + c + c .............................(3)$

Similarly,  $T(n-10) = T(n-15) + c ....................(4)$

Substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$, gives

$T(n) = T(n-15) + c + c + c .........................(5)$

and so on.

Finally, $T(n) = T(k) + \frac{cn}{5}$ where $k<=4$

then $T(n) = 1 + \frac{cn}{5}$

therefore $f(n)=O(n)$ as $\frac{c}{5}$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you for this, but this is all assuming that T(n) = T(n-5) + C I am not sure that is the proper equation from the pseudo code.